# How do I use PHP on a Rails server?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a site in Ruby on Rails, but I also need to incorporate some PHP scripts.  How do I get PHP running on a Rails server?  If it's not possible, what alternative method can I use?

Comment: To clarify, do these PHP scripts generate webpages?

Comment: google found me many answers.

Comment: A "Rails server" is any machine capable of running Ruby. Can you be more specific about your architecture? IaaS/dedicated hosting, PaaS, or shared hosting? Are you using Apache, Nginx, something else, or nothing? Is your Rails code being served by Unicorn/Mongrel/Thin/Puma/Passenger?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, I once incorporated a WordPress blog into a rails application.  You need to override Passenger and tell it to ignore your php script directory.

I placed a **cms** directory inside the public directory of the Rails app. Then in the apache config file (or vhost.conf) I put the following:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/app/public

<Directory /path/to/app/public>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /cms>
  PassengerEnabled off
</Location>
```

It's the last part **PassengerEnabled off** that does the magic.  Check out this link:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerEnabled

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

When you mention you need to *"incorporate"* PHP scripts in your Rails app, do you mean you need to run PHP scripts within the Rails app, or run PHP scripts on the rails / ruby server?

There is a distinct difference between the two:

```
PHP == Ruby
PHP != Rails
```

When you run a Rails server, you've got a "closed" environment. It won't be able to read any external data from sources other than `Ruby` / `Rails` - you'll have to use some third party web service to do that, such as an API

--

**Server**

As `Mark Kenny` recommended, you can easily install PHP & Ruby on a server, running them side-by-side with ease. The important thing is to setup your server configuration correctly, as to allow the right people to work with the right system at the right time

If you're trying to incorporate a PHP system *into* your Rails app, it simply won't work. It's bad systemic design, and generally will cause massive headaches down the line

The thing I would do is either replicate the functionality of your PHP system inside your Rails app (depending on how big your budget is / how long you have), *or* look at how you may be able to simply integrate the PHP system through a web service into your rails app